# Is it acceptable to trigger Dependency injection at multiple levels?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, guice

Is it acceptable to trigger Dependency injection at multiple levels?

Let me provide an example:
Say I own a service with an api that returns a bunch of restaurants near a provided gps location.

At the time of service start, I want to employ Dependency injection to instantiate the global objects (Example: a GpsCoordinatesToCountryState translator class).

When a request comes in for the api getRestaurants(GpsLocation), I want to again employ Dependency Injection to instantiate the objects that are invoked to find the restaurants near the given location. For example, I might want to use polymorphism to handle users in USA and India differently for certain classes.

Is this approach acceptable or does it violate any DI usage best practices?

Comment: You might want to try to use some code examples. For me, your question doesn't make much sense. Maybe with some code example of what you are talking about might help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because in its current state, it belongs to the Software Engineering sister site